# RadDropDownTree show selected value without hierarchy

Tags: c#, telerik

I want to show only the selected node text rather than showing entire hierarchy of node after selecting node.

Comment: Good.. Any effort so far?

Answer (score 0):

Is the TextMode property set to FullPath? If so, try setting it to Default.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree/examples/functionality/textmode/defaultcs.aspx